# Can I add .NET Standard libraries to PCL

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, .net-standard

I have a Xamarin Forms app and using Visual Studio 2015.

1) Can I add to PCL .NET Standard libraries? Are there any issues with that?

2) Editing resx of a .NET Standard library crashes VS2015. Any workaround?

Comment: "PCL" and ".NET Standard" are completely different concepts. Don't use VS2015 for .NET Core/.NET Standard stuffs. Period.

Comment: Meh. I know they're completely difference concepts. I found a lot of references which mention about using VS2015 for .NET Standard. Why do you say "don't use"?.

Comment: The only official supported IDE for .NET Core/.NET Standard is VS2017. The tooling shipped for VS2015 was just a preview build, and should be avoided in all cases.

Comment: Oh, that isn't clearly communicated. Just look to Xamarin's own blog post from less than a month ago: https://blog.xamarin.com/building-xamarin-forms-apps-net-standard/  They say `If you’re using Visual Studio 2015, be sure to follow our getting started guide to create and convert a Portable Class Library to a .NET Standard library.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add .Net standard libraries to PCLs, but only lower versions. It depends on your profile version, so you almost have to try it and see if it works.

You can add PCLs to .Net standard libraries, by setting a fallback to the PCL in your csproj file. You can read about it here: https://oren.codes/2017/04/23/using-xamarin-forms-with-net-standard-vs-2017-edition/

Comment: I noticed I don't need to do anything. By NuGet, I can install the latest versions of different libraries I am using in the app, and these libraries have .NET Support. It just that it adds a lot of libraries.

Comment: Oren's blog post doesn't mention anything about `Microsoft.NETCore.Portable.Compatibility`...