# Add Reference to another project in Portable Class Library

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, mvvmcross

I have a common PCL project, and I created a DAL (.Net Standard 2.0 Library) project and added a link to PCL, but I can not access the DAL classes:

[image]

[image]

**EDIT: Add DAL example code**

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace AproReports.DAL.Services.RequestProvider
{
    public interface IRequestProvider
    {
        Task<TResult> GetAsync<TResult>(string uri, string token = "");

        Task<TResult> PostAsync<TResult>(string uri, TResult data, string token = "", string header = "");

        Task<TResult> PutAsync<TResult>(string uri, TResult data, string token = "", string header = "");

        Task DeleteAsync(string uri, string token = "");
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share the code of one of the class of `AproReports.DAL` library which you want to access?

Comment: Yea, i updated question

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45286656/can-i-add-net-standard-libraries-to-pcl

Comment: Portable Class Libraries cannot consume .NET Standard unless they are profile 1.0 or 1.1. It also depends on the PCL profile if these can be consumed at all.