# Error when Inheres from class in another assembly

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.uwp

I'm using Xamarin forms for Android, iOS, and UWP. but all my EF Models are in a separate Dot NET Standard project (called ERP.Common) to be used in another ASP.NET Core solution.

Moreover, I'm extended some class from ERP.Common project in my Xaamrin Forms project to implement private properties like implementing INotifyPropertyChanged for example. and it's works fine with Android project (not tested in iOS project) but I'm getting the following errors on UWP project.

Any ideas?

```
Cannot resolve Assembly or Windows Metadata file 'Type universe cannot resolve assembly: ERP.Common, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null.'
```

[image]

### Update 1

it works fine in UWP project if I create an object from the class Model without extending it. which make me sure that the DLL already registered successfully. I Think :)

And both targeting same .Net Standard version 2.0

Comment: Check this link how to add class library DLL in PCL - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45286656/can-i-add-net-standard-libraries-to-pcl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my case, I've upgraded the version of .net standard to 2.0.3 and it works fine.

Comment: also cleaned the project and re-build

Comment: Thanks, dev for your answer it's helped. I was about to forget about this issue :)